# Codeigniter JOIN - not a unique table/alias issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have bookings tables from several countries (for example: book_uk) these tables contain information about our customers in different countries such as name, address, etc etc. Then in my results table I have the results of all tests this customer has had, the information is 'linked' by a PIN number, eg 336699, this number is referenced in both the book_uk table and the results table.

What I want to do is select all data from the book_uk table and then link each row to the results table (where the PIN matches) but I keep getting not a unique table/alias, here is my model code:

```
$database->select($new_country_columns)
     ->from($country_table);
$database->select($p_results_cols)
     ->from($table);
$database->join('p_results', $join, 'inner');
```

`$database` is defined earlier on in the model

Produces this error:

```
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'p_results'

SELECT `book_uk`.`pin`, `book_uk`.`clinic`, `book_uk`.`dob`, `book_uk`.`gender`, `book_uk`.`country`, `book_uk`.`order_date`, `p_results`.`pin`, `p_results`.`code`, `p_results`.`name`, `p_results`.`result` FROM (`book_uk`, `p_results`) INNER JOIN `p_results` ON 'book_uk.pin = p_results.pin'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/b2k-stat/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

what I really need to do is select data from book_uk and then run a foreach loop on the results table and add any data with matching PIN to the results array, I have no idea how to do this, I tried to loop through it with a foreach loop but it kept coming up blank, i've also tried:

```
$database->select($new_country_columns)
     ->from($country_table)
     ->join('p_results', $join, 'inner');
```

But this also gives me zero results, any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
'p_results'
```

from your

```
FROM
```

clause since your joining it right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do things, but I solved my issue by generating 2 queries and running an IF statement inside a foreach loop on both queries like so:

```
$database->select($new_country_columns)
     ->from($country_table);
$query1 = $database->get()->result_array();
$p_results->select($p_results_cols)
     ->from($table);
$query2 = $p_results->get()->result_array();

foreach($query1 as $row){
    foreach($query2 as $rows) {
        if($row['pin'] === $rows['pin']) {
            $new_row = array_merge($row, $rows);
            $query[] = $new_row;
        }
   }
}
return $query;
```

This code gave me an array of the combined data that was needed to display in my view